# Get time and timezone from new Date()

Tags: javascript

When I try to do  `var d = new Date()` what I get is `Thu Sep 28 2017 22:13:25 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)`

Is there any way I can get `"22:13:25"` and `"GMT-0500"` into two different variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let currentTime = new Date();
let offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
let dateFormat = { hour: 'numeric', minute:'numeric', second: 'numeric', hour12: false };
let value = null;
let timeZone = null;

console.log(currentTime.toLocaleString('en-US', dateFormat));

if (offset < 0) {
  value = '+';
  timeZone = offset/-60;
} else {
  value = '-';
  timeZone = offset/60;
}

if (timeZone < 10) {
  console.log('Your timezone: GMT' + value + '0' + timeZone + '00');
} else {
  console.log('Your timezone: GMT' + value + + timeZone + '00');
}
```

That's it

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

```js
var d = new Date()
var time = d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes() + ":" + d.getSeconds(); 
var gmt = "GMT" + (d.toString().split('GMT')[1]);

console.log(time)
console.log(gmt)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

If you need an explanation - feel free to ask!